# Shell script to Become root?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, root

How can we write a shell script to become root?
That is I donot want to input the password at prompt it should be within the script itself. I was trying to make but failed to do so.Is it possible, if Yes please Explain.

Comment: Doing this would be a huge security risk.

Comment: It is a risk, but if you're gung ho about it: `echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S $COMMAND` from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=791719 might work

Answer (score 7):

Do not do this. Instead, learn your particular system's built-in features for executing commands with escalated privileges. Look at `sudo` and the `sudoers` file, if you happen to be on a Linux that supports that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expect script for that. Or if you are looking to execute commands as root user then you can use "su -c" option for that.

For incorporating it inside a script you can use something like this :-

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn su
set timeout 60
expect "pass" {
sleep 1
send "<my_root_password>"
} timeout {
send_user "Error connecting"
}
interact
```

For this you need to have expect binaries present in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is with [SUID](http://www.diablotin.com/librairie/networking/puis/ch05_05.htm) Shell Scripts but it isn't safe, the right way instead is sudo.

Comment: And doesn't work with shell scripts, only with binaries.

Comment: I mean to get root without input password!

Comment: "Under most versions of UNIX, you can create shell scripts[ that are SUID or SGID. That is, you can create a shell script and, by setting the shell script's owner to be root and setting its SUID bit, you can force the shell script to execute with superuser privileges." Practical UNIX and Internet Security 2nd

Comment: mmm... did you try that? I once did so, and at least under Linux it didn't work. But even if it works, it is unsafe, as yo already wrote.

Comment: BTW: You contradict yourself; you cannot call something "the best way" if it isn't safe and there is another right way.

Comment: I mean The best way to get root password without input! Yes I did, I have that book since the 1990s!!!